# Angular2 watch for route change

Tags: typescript, angular

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/test', name: 'Test', component: Test}
])

export class MyApp {
    router: Router;
    location: Location;
    isCollapsed: boolean = true;

    // ON ROUTE CHANGE {
        this.isCollapsed = true;
    // }

    constructor(router: Router, location: Location) {
        this.router = router;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

I need change variable value on every route change, how to watch for this event in Angular 2.x?

Comment: For the new router (=> RC.3) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137455/angular-2-typescript-error-when-using-subscribe-function-on-new-router-rc-1/37137497#37137497

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the **final version** of Angular (e.g. Angular 2/4), you can do this

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if(event.url) {
        console.log(event.url);
    }
});
```

Every time the route changes, `events` Observable has the info.
Click [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#events-anchor) for **docs**.

Comment: This did the trick! Please note that the router element is an instance of Router: you should ```import {Router} from '@angular/router';``` and ```constructor(private router: Router) { }```.

Comment: property url does not exist on type event.

Comment: Can you answer for this question? sixtwo49843nine

Comment: There are now multiple event types in Angular, so you'll need to check the event type first. Then you can use the specific properties of each. E.g., `if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) { event.url...; }`  See docs here for more types: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd

Answer (score 20):

If you are using

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7", 
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

then

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log('route changed');
});
```

Comment: This is correct answer for current versions. Goli this was hard to find. +1

Comment: +1 Your answer is valid for the current version(s) of Angular2. `this.router.subscribe()` does not work anymore. Instead you need to subscribe to the `events` like stated by Dimpu!

Answer (score 17):

Here's what I use in my app. You can subscribe to a Route instance to track changes.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.subscribe((val) => /*detect changes*/)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, down-voted this before you changed the answer for Angular2, this is correct

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.

Comment: @ulydev will you please provide plnkr or working code for this routerChange detection i cannot get you How to use your code.

Comment: router.subscribe does not fire with angular beta.2
any idea ?

Comment: Try    this.router.changes.subscribe

Answer (score 4):

event is observable so you can subscribe to it, I have successfully tried it in angular5

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
console.log(event);
 if(event['url'] && event['url'] == '/') {
    console.log('Home page');
    //any other functionality you can do here
 }
});
```

Comment: valid answer on angular 6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the event when the route changes, and initialize some code like jQuery then use `OnActive` hook.
For example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnActivate,ComponentInstruction} from "angular2/router";
declare var $:any;
declare var Foundation:any;
@Component({
templateUrl :'/app/templates/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnActivate{

  routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction)
  {

    new Foundation.Orbit($("#es-slide-show"), {});
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it:

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router'

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((evt: RouterEvent) => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe((evt: RouterEvent) => {
    // with the above filter, both the following will always log the same url
    console.log(evt.url)
    console.log(this.router.url)
  })
}
```