# Angular 2 typescript error when using subscribe function on new router (rc 1)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to set up authentication for my Angular 2 app with the new router. Someone suggested to try the following:

```
constructor (private _router: Router) {} 

ngOnInit(){
  this._router.subscribe(
    next => {
      if (!userIsLoggedInOrWhatever) {
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
      }
    }
  )    
}
```

This problem however is that this results in the typescript error

> (app.component.ts(47,22): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Router'.

This is strange because the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html#!#subscribe-anchor) clearly shows that a Router object does have this function. I am able to call other functions like router.navigate(['/url']). Do you guys have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**new router**

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  })
}
```

**original**

The `Router` class has an `EventEmitter` `changes` you can subscribe to:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._router.changes.subscribe(
    next => {
      if (!userIsLoggedInOrWhatever) {
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
      }
    }
  )    
}
```

For how to get the previous route see [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657) (`pairwise()`)

Comment: could you please offer an example on how to accomplish this in the app.ts where the bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ... ] is also found? I am running into a number of different errors in my various attempts to get this working in my app.ts: "EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'changes' of undefined", "EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!", "angular2-polyfills.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: ReferenceError: router is not defined", "angular2-polyfills.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'changes' of undefined"

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? Above code works with RC.1 `@angular/router` but not with `@angular/router-deprecated`

Comment: nice work but how to detect the previous route, from where the app is coming to which route ?

Comment: The `pairwise()` operator should help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657