# Angular route with Query Parameter and Appended Route

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, query-string

I am using angular 9 application.

I have a routing file with the below code :

```
{ path: 'a/:id', component: AComponent },
{ path: 'a/b', component: BComponent },
{ path: 'a/c', component: CComponent }
```

I want to have the same route `'a'` with query parameter `id` as well as appended routes (b & c)

When I am trying to navigate to `'a/b'` OR `'a/c'`, the URL in the browser gets updated, however, it doesn't actually navigates to the desired route.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Route `a/:id` match all cases. If you really need this kind of routes, try to change the order of elements. The most generic rule should be last.

Comment: In vueJs this is common and you need to `watch` the route, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444822/angular2-watch-for-route-change/42963148

Comment: @KarolTrybulec Yes you are correct...Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

In your case:

```
{ path: 'a/b', component: BComponent },
{ path: 'a/c', component: CComponent },
{ path: 'a/:id', component: AComponent },
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this simple thing. Thank you so much!